# Struggling with Creating a Shell in C

Tags: c

I've been struggling to implement a basic shell. I understand the basic concept and I've gotten as far as receiving a seg-fault. I basically need to implement a shell by doing:

1. prompt
2. parse input
3. create argv[]
4. fork
   child -> execvp()
   parent -> wait/waitpid()

The code I have is listed below and I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong I've looked at numerous other places. My initial thought is that it has to do with strtok() but I haven't been able to pinpoint it.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    char input[100];
    char* p[20];
    int numofargs;
    char* s;

        while(1){   
            printf("SimpleShell");
            fgets(input, 100, stdin);
            s = strtok(input, " ");
            while(p[numofargs] != NULL){
                p[numofargs] = strtok (NULL, " ");
                numofargs++;
                }
            pid = fork();
                if (pid == 0){
                    execvp(p[0],p);
                    perror("exec failure ");
                    }
                else
                    waitpid();
        }   
exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What is `p` used for?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `p` is an array of pointers to `char`.  It is *uninitialized* to start, meaning each entry `p[n]` (i.e. each of `p`'s 20 elements where 0 <= n < 20) is garbage.  Yet the first thing you do with it is test to see if one of its items is `NULL`.  That's crashtastic.  Also, you haven't initialized `numofargs`, so which element of `p` are you accessing?  Who knows.  That is also crashtastic.  Start by fixing those things.